# How can I have data be different for three identical blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I differentiate three different blocks that look exactly the same from each other? I want to have command blocks be able to tell them apart because they have different data, and **I cannot use their location as the different data factor**, because I need the command blocks to find them no matter where they are in the world. **I want them all to look exactly the same.** I am also open to suggestions of things that don't necessarily get this accomplished, but still allows command blocks to tell them apart without changing the appearance of the blocks. Overall, I want command blocks to be able to tell three different blocks apart from each other that are all Yellow Wool blocks. I do not want the appearance of any of the blocks to be changed in any way.

Comment: So you're looking for a command that can identify three *physically* identical blocks, regardless of location? I'm not sure, because you can change the `Name` of a block in an anvil, but this gets wiped when you place it. So perhaps there is another tag you can use to identify them?

Comment: A better headline pls

Comment: @SimonMeusel you can edit it yourself.

Comment: @Ben Yes, I do need them to be physically identical, but I want a command block to be able to tell them apart without using their location.

Comment: You could use diffrent block but make their textures the same with a resource pack

Comment: for blocks without metadata variants you can use metadata

Comment: The blocks can differ only in ID, metadata or in NBT tags, but those NBTs have only TileEntities. That would need NEW block hosting TileEntity, or some asociated TileEntity/Entity (like in the Skylinerw's answer - he adds the Entity that can hold the data) . Better aproach would be to make a mod with your own block, that will have TileEntity and NBT datatag just like you want(or just metadata difference). But that can be no option if you want to stay vanilla, therefore you can only use workarounds with entities (because you CANNOT add TileEntity to any block without consequences)

Answer (score 0):

You can visually simulate a block using FallingSand, as well as a Shulker to simulate the bounding box of the block. The host entity would have the unique identifiers while there still appears to be a block.

Unfortunately if the FallingSand is too close to the ground, it will land. But in the latest 1.10 snapshot (16w21b), the `NoGravity` tag has been extended to all entities, and allows the FallingSand to be above the ground without landing.

For example, given the following arrangement of an armor stand host that has a Shulker and FallingSand as its passengers:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {Tags:["wool1"],Passengers:[{id:"FallingSand",Block:"minecraft:wool",Data:4,Time:-2147483648,NoGravity:1b},{id:"Shulker",NoAI:1b,Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}]}],Invisible:1b,Marker:1b}
```

The "wool1" tag indicates that this host is the first yellow wool. You would create copies of this entity while changing that tag to be different:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {Tags:["wool2"],Passengers:[{id:"FallingSand",Block:"minecraft:wool",Data:4,Time:-2147483648,NoGravity:1b},{id:"Shulker",NoAI:1b,Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}]}],Invisible:1b,Marker:1b}
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {Tags:["wool3"],Passengers:[{id:"FallingSand",Block:"minecraft:wool",Data:4,Time:-2147483648,NoGravity:1b},{id:"Shulker",NoAI:1b,Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}]}],Invisible:1b,Marker:1b}
```

And you can then target those specific hosts:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,tag=wool2] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:stone
```